# String with date range bug impala

Tags: sql, impala, truncate, date-range

I'm trying to get a string with date range of dates, such as "W202243 from 24-Oct a 30-Oct", going from each monday to sunday. To achieve this i'm using impala, creating the string step by step.
My function is:
`select distinct concat('W',substr(cast(a.day_key AS string),1,4), IF (DAYOFWEEK(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(cast(a.day_key AS string) AS string), "yyyyMMdd")))=2, cast(weekofyear(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(cast(a.day_key AS string) AS string), "yyyyMMdd")))-1 AS string), cast(weekofyear(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(cast(a.day_key AS string) AS string), "yyyyMMdd"))) AS string)), ' from ', SUBSTR(substr(cast(TRUNC(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(a.day_key AS string), "yyyyMMdd")),-1),'DY') AS string), 9,10),1,2), '-', SUBSTR(MONTHNAME(date_add(TRUNC(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(a.day_key AS string), "yyyyMMdd")),-1),'DY'),1)),1,3),' a ', SUBSTR(substr(cast(date_add(TRUNC(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(a.day_key AS string), "yyyyMMdd")),-1),'DY'),6) AS string), 9,10),1,2), '-', SUBSTR(MONTHNAME(date_add(TRUNC(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(a.day_key AS string), "yyyyMMdd")),-1),'DY'),6)),1,3))`

The result is almost correct, except when the first day of week is also the last of month, giving me this unwanted result: (Ex. W202244 FROM 31-Nov a 06-Nov -> November instead of October).
Any ideias of what can i add to the query to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

While this reads like plain English it seems that specific phrases are being used as "delimiters". You can use the CHARINDEX function to break this statement down into 3 columns, then from there cast/convert each column into it's final form. You could probably do this all in 1 step but it would be a mess to write and to read and I'm not sure if it would offer any performance benefit

You could also use REPLACE to turn this column into a delimited string, then parse that. For example:

```
declare @string nvarchar(max) = 'W202243 from 24-Oct a 30-Oct'

select REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, ' from ', ','),' a ', ',')
```

This returns:

```
W202243,24-Oct,30-Oct
```

Which is comma delimited. You can change the delimiter to whatever. But from there it would be easy to get 3 distinct columns and convert them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering to my question. That's a good advice, but in my context, i just need to correct the query that i already have, so the issue should be in the monthname or the trunc + date_add combo, to get the proper interval of dates. Do you have any ideia about that, in specific?

Comment: dateadd will correctly increase the month (or should increase it) without looping back to the start of the month. If it's doing that, it might imply you have some logic error when returning the dates. I could dig through the entire line of code you've written but honestly the readability is very poor. I'd suggest doing this in more than one step - you don't stand to gain much from doing pure string manipulation in line. I don't know the whole solution however so i don't know what limitation you're facing that necessitates a monolithic select in one line.